# How to solve this issue `OpenCV: scale factor must be > 1...` ? in OpenCV wrap up?

Tags: c#, image-processing, opencv

Hi I am writing an `Application` to count the number of `faces` in an `images`. I am using `Haar_caash_code` xml for count the faces.

C# Code:

```
   private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog opndlg = new OpenFileDialog();

        if (opndlg.ShowDialog().Equals(DialogResult.OK))
        {
            try
            {
                Image img = Image.FromFile(opndlg.FileName);
                Image<Bgr, byte> BgrImg = new Image<Bgr, byte>(new Bitmap(img));
                GrayImage = BgrImg.Convert<Gray, byte>();
                var faces = GrayImage.DetectHaarCascade(haar, 1, 4, HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING, new Size(25, 25))[0]; //here Exception
                MessageBox.Show(faces.Length.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

and dlls included:

```
 cudart64_32_16.dll
 cufft64_32_16.dll
 cvextern.dll
 npp64_32_16.dll
 opencv_calib3d220.dll
 opencv_contrib220.dll
 opencv_core220.dll
 opencv_features2d220.dll
 opencv_flann220.dll
 opencv_gpu220.dll
 opencv_highgui220.dll
 opencv_imgproc220.dll
 opencv_legacy220.dll
 opencv_ml220.dll
 opencv_objdetect220.dll
 opencv_video220.dll
```

I get the following error when I run the program:

```
 `OpenCV: scale factor must be > 1...`
```

Please help with how to resolve the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter `scale factor` to `DetectHaarCascade` has to be strictly greater that 1.
To be sure of this try setting it to 1.1 and see if the program works without errors.

```
var faces = GrayImage.DetectHaarCascade(haar, 1.1, // change this value
     4, HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING, new Size(25, 25))[0];
```

Read [this](http://fewtutorials.bravesites.com/entries/emgu-cv-c/level-3c---how-to-improve-face-detection) post for further information.

Comment: it removes exception. But didn't count no of faces.